# How to activate pattern found at the base of second tower in Tyranny (sunset spire, lethinian's crossing)

Tags: tyranny

I got stuck with activating the pattern at the base of second tower in Tyranny (sunset spire, lethinian's crossing).

I just cant figure out how to do it in such a way that all the lines would light up in one go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... so what you need to do is reclick already active nodes and then click the nodes next to them, this way you can make multiple 'short' lines and finish the patter

I also made a video as this one was not obvious to me at all...

Hope this saves you some time

Comment: @Oak I answer most of my own questions...

Comment: It's just the way it was phrased it seemed like you were answering to someone else;) Either way, the video is fixed so i deleted the prev comment